# Set a flag on a table based on dependent flags in another table with sql

Tags: php, sql, database

I would like to set a boolean column in one table based on every row from another table.

For example: I have 3 tables; Table B is the N:M relation between table A and C

> Table A: ID, flag
>
> Table B: A-ID, C-ID
>
> Table C: ID, flag

I want to set a.flag to false if only 1 c.flag row is false.

I tried with different case statements but I always get errors or something like this because I'm still learning how to use sql correctly

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, no images. (And take a look at [mcve] before you start.)

Comment: What if there are multiple records in Table C for a given record in Table A, with different flag values? Also, what if there is no corresponding record in Table C ?

Comment: Please tag your question with the RDBMS that you are using: oracle, mysql, sql-server...?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
update a
    set flag = (case when exists (select 1
                                  from b join
                                       c
                                       on b.a_id = c.a_id
                                  where c.flag = 'false'
                                 )
                     then 'false' else 'true'
                end);
```

You haven't specified the database, so I have used strings for the values.

If you specifically want *exactly* one row, then you would use aggregation:

```
update a
    set flag = (case when 1 = (select count(*)
                               from b join
                                    c
                                    on b.a_id = c.a_id
                               where c.flag = 'false'
                              )
                     then 'false' else 'true'
                end);
```